# How can I programmatically access zsh completion?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

zsh has a completion system, activated by pressing tab:

```
llama@llama:~$ git st<Tab>
Completing main porcelain command
stash      -- stash away changes to dirty working directory
status     -- show working-tree status
Completing plumbing internal helper command
stripspace -- filter out empty lines
```

All I've been able to figure out is that this comes from the script `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git`, where `_git` is the completion command being called.

Assuming I know the name of the completion function (e.g. `_git`), how could I get the output of what would happen if I entered a certain string and pressed tab? Essentially, I'm trying to take an input of ex. `git st` and get the output above (programmatically, from a script).

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6713391/1223693) other [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24514143/1223693) questions [about](https://serverfault.com/q/231282/186515) this [for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124236/45600) bash, but I haven't found anything explaining how to achieve this with zsh.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260544/calling-zsh-completion-function-and-obtaining-its-results

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by using [zsh-capture-completion](https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion). The repository's README.md file provides several examples:

```
capture.zsh 'vim -'
capture.zsh 'vim --'
capture.zsh 'vim --r'
capture.zsh 'echo *('
capture.zsh 'scp hostname:'
```

Note that the package itself states that it is a proof of concept, and as such may contain errors in its execution.